# What e-mail header is needed for a message to be displayed as 'via:'?

Tags: php

I have noticed that some mails come with the from address like :

> Adam Mannet  via www.findyourfriend.com.

What headers do I need to pass to the native PHP `mail()` function to accomplish this when sending e-mail?

Comment: If you view the source of a message that has a "via" header in it, you should be able to see what the header that is used is. If you are not sure maybe post the raw source of the headers here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the via tag is added by the mail server when somebody uses an external (from his domain) smtp server.
Per example,
my email is iceduck@iceduck.net but I send email via Gmail's smtp, you will see From iceduck@iceduck.net via Gmail.com.
If you want to make the via appear then you'll have to send your mail through the smtp server you want to appear in the via.
You can check out this link : http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

I don't think the solution is in the header.

Best

Answer (score 0):

You should check [PHP `mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) documentation. There is a description how to modify 'From' header. You should use additional_headers to change that header information and include 'friendly name' beside your e-mail address.

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "Message content";
$headers = 'From: User Name <user@example.com>';

// Send
mail('test@example.com', 'My Subject', $message, $headers);
?>
```

This should make your from address look like: 'User Name via www.example.com'

Comment: Marcin, I know this. what i wanted to know is how to add the via tag to the header.

Comment: I think that 'via' is added by mail system and you cannot force it to appear. What mail/webmail do you use? I don't think there is any 'via' in gmail eg.

Comment: i am using gmail. well if that is added by the mail system then there isnt anything that I can do

Comment: 'via' on gmail has a bit different meaning: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=pl&answer=1311182&ctx=mail